# TBB error when compiling

Tags: c++, c++11, tbb

I have the following piece of code that i am trying to execute

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include "tbb/tbb.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace tbb;

class Accumulate{
    float& arr;
    float* src;

    public:
    Accumulate(float& _arr, float* _src)
    :arr(_arr), src(_src){}
    void operator() (int i) const{
        arr += src[i];
    }

};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    float arr[4] = {1,3,9,27};
    float sum = 0;
    parallel_for(0, 4, Accumulate(sum, arr));
    cout<< sum << endl;  
}
```

I am trying to make use of **parllel_for** to calculate the sum and this requires the tbb library. I downloaded the source tbb directory and pasted it in my xcode project directory.

When i try to compile the above code, i seem to get the following error
**'tbb/internal/_flow_graph_types_impl.h' file not found**

I am not sure what i am missing, please advise

Answer (score 3):

I can see this file in TBB repo: https://github.com/01org/tbb/blob/tbb_2017/include/tbb/internal/_flow_graph_types_impl.h

Please make sure that your installation of TBB is not damaged.

Off-topic advice, there is a data-race in your program on `sum` and you can use lambda instead of explicit functor:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    float arr[4] = {1,3,9,27};
    atomic<float> sum = 0; // fixing data-race. Still, it's not recommended way
    parallel_for(0, 4, [&](int i){
        sum += arr[i];
    });
    cout<< sum << endl;  
}
```

See also `tbb::parallel_reduce` in order to make this code correct, clean, and efficient.